# Makefile generic rule to build src files from multiple folders

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I intend to keep my all *.o files build/obj and have source files src/src.c log/log.c

```
OBJECTS=build/log.o build/src.o

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : src/%.c log/%.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINE) $(INCLUDE) -o$@ $<
```

But it not mapping *.o to proper *.c what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: $(OBJDIR)/%.o : src/%.c , this works when one folder is there. But I would like to map to c files from multiple folders

Comment: You can do this using `VPATH`.  (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)).   I'm not a huge fan of `VPATH` as it makes it harder to figure out what a makefile is doing, but it does what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried VPATH, VPATH = src:log , it didn't work for me , first file builds next doesn't . when added VPATH , I modified pre requisite to %.c

Comment: I wanted to add one more thing ,this works(It maps .o to .c properly) "$(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/,%.c)" when only one src folder and multiple c files are there inside the source folder

Comment: Hmmm. you'll have to post your makefile with vpath.   I just tried and it worked for me.   I'll post mine in an answer...

Comment: BTW, you can use backticks to `highlight` source code in comments (or in posts for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VPATH` as follows:

```
~/tmp8> more Makefile

OBJECTS=build/log.o build/src.o
OBJ_DIR=build

all: $(OBJECTS)

VPATH=src:log

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        @echo compiling "$< ==> $@"
```

---

```
~/tmp8> find . -type f
./src/src.c
./Makefile
./log/log.c    

~/tmp8> make
compiling log/log.c ==> build/log.o
compiling src/src.c ==> build/src.o

~/tmp8>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , only after sorting folder name not sure why. make version that I have is "4.1"